# Rename the multiple column when .groupby.agg(['sum'])

Tags: python

How to rename the multiple column when `.groupby.agg(['sum'])`?

```
dk = new_df1.groupby(['Product','Date'])['Sale1', 'Sale2'].agg(['sum']).reset_index().rename(columns={'sum':'First_Sale', 'Second_Sale'})
```

It will show `First_Sale, sum` for the Sale1 column and `Second_Sale, sum` for the Sale2 column.

Anyone can assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: Note that I removed `[]` around `'sum'` and added them around the column names `'Sale1', 'Sale2'`:

```
rename = {'Sale1': 'First_Sale', 'Sale2': 'Second_Sale'}

dk = new_df1.groupby(['Product', 'Date'])[['Sale1', 'Sale2']].agg('sum').reset_index().rename(columns=rename)
```